# AngularJS $http GET method to backend server: Request Method:OPTIONS 405

Tags: angularjs, clojure

$http GET request to a clojure  backend, to get a list of services.
I get is an OPTIONS request (???), which gets a 405 response...

```
<code>
var config = {headers:  {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer d2VudHdvYW5nZV9tZQ',
        "X-Testing" : "testing"
    }
};
$http.get(SERVER.MESSAGE_SERVICES, config)
  .success(function(successCallback) {
    $scope.services = successCallback;
  })
  .error(function(errorCallback) {
    console.log(errorCallback.toString);
  }).
finally(function() {
  console.log("Message services rest call");
});
</code>

**clojure  backend**:
<code>
headers {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "X-Requested-With, Origin,Content-Type, Accept"
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS"}
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem that AngularJS sends an OPTIONS request, that is because CORS standards force to do so. Be sure that the server is configured to allow a GET method.

Comment: In my backend I have added:
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS" this will allow GET services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as raso suggested this problem is because of Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS). The same old privacy policy prevents JS/ angularJS from making requests across domain boundaries.

Configure server to allow cross domain requests.
Or
If you are using Chrome than you can use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to surpass this problem.